# "Checked into the database" versus "checked in to the database"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should “into” be used rather than “in to,” and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/when-should-into-be-used-rather-than-in-to-and-vice-versa)

I was recently submitting ("checking in") some data to a database and composed an email to my team informing them of the submission. What's the proper grammar to use here:

> The changes are checked into the database

or

> The changes are checked in to the database

What's the rule of thumb for proper usage between the two? Is there even a difference?

Comment: @RegDwight, I agree. The other question even has a much better answer.

Comment: In my case, it is more correct to check code into TFS.

Comment: Actually, the one reported by @RegDwight has been closed in favor of the one reported by @MrHen.

Comment: *In to* is correct.

Comment: _Correct_ accdording to which authority, @SebastianPojman?

Comment: English has no major authority figure, unlike Spanish, so finding one is sometimes a waste of time. *Sometimes.* 

In the end, *in to* is correct because the adverb *in* is part of the phrasal verb *check in*, meaning "to incorporate into," "to add to," or "to register."

Comment: Also, the way you worded it sounds marginally hostile...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, definitely write it as separate words, because the "in" is actually part of the idiom "checked in".

I think that's probably as close as you're gonna get to a rule of thumb: write *into* as one word, unless it's actually functioning as two different words - for example, if the "in" is part of an expression such as "checked in".

Answer (score 7):

No, "into" does not require that the destination be a physical place. One can be brought into poverty, a relationship, a realisation ...

So I would definitely check code into Subversion.

Comment: I hadn't considered these other, even more abstract, concepts. The important thing, I think, is that after being "brought into" those things, it makes sense at a conceptual level of "being inside" those things. Not so much with turning a wallet "in to" a policeman.

Comment: Um, but the verb here is not *to check*. The verb is *to check in*.  So *to check into* is not even an option. The actual choice is between *check in to* and *check in into*.

Comment: @RegDwight. Hmm, good point. Or "checkin to". But my "check code into", though it might be a haplology, is definitely what I would say or write.

Comment: @RegDwight: good point. I did a quick Google search with "check in to a hotel", and it responded with, "Did you mean 'check into a hotel'?" Thus sayeth Google. (Not that this proves anything, of course.)

Comment: IMHO the natural idiom is *to check in* when using the verb intransitively, and *to check into X* when using the verb with an object.

Comment: @RegDwight - I think "check into" may in effect be an elliptical form of "check in into" -- see my answer below.

Comment: @Colin Fine: We can eliminate "checkin" because that is the noun.  The verb is written "check in" to reflect that it is not a single unit and elements can intervene (e.g. "check the file in").

Comment: Agree with @JSBangs. The inconsistency seems like a quirk of English, but I think this is how most people probably use it.

Comment: *In to* is correct here.

Answer (score 4):

There's actually evidence for treating a case such as "check in/to SVN" as a kind of elliptical form of "check in into", when you consider the possible combinations when you turn the sentence round. Compare the possibility of the following:

> Which repository did you check it
>   into?
>
> Which repository did you check it in
>   into?
>
> Into which repository did you check it
>   in?

with the impossibility of the following:

> *Into which repository did you check it?
>
> *To which repository did you check it in?

From this point of view, it seems a bit more logical to write "check (in) into", whether or not you include the second "in".

Comment: My very thoughts. In OP's case it just so happens that *to check in* is a compound verb phrase of special relevance to packages like SVN.

Comment: *In to* is correct. Also, you're way off. *To which repository did you check it in?* is correct, not *into which*.

Answer (score 2):

I think both are definitely allowable.

- You can treat the verb 'check in' separately from 'toSVN because there is a direct object possible, for example 'my code':

> I checked in my code to SVN.

This shows that the 'in' and 'to' are separable.

- You can use the preposition 'into' with 'check'. SVN, and other abstract repositories, still have a semantic connotation of being a receptacle or having an interior. Using the separability check:

> I checked my code into SVN.

This shows that SVN acts like it has an interior.

The verb 'to log in' acts similarly.

Which is preferred? I find 'checked in to SVN' better than 'checked into SVN', because I tend to use 'checkin' more often. Compare contrast with 'check out': I like 'check out my code' but 'check out of svn' (and despite appearances, 'out of' corresponds to 'into').

Comment: Good answer. As I indicated in another comment, I would probably use "check into" most of the time, but I think "check in to" is fine as well (as you said, compare it to "log in", e.g. "log in to the website"). The ones that I completely disagree with are those that make a verb phrase that combines the verb and the preposition into one word (e.g. "login", "setup", which I think are acceptable as nouns, but not as verbs...but that's probably a topic for another thread).

Answer (score 1):

In the sense that your source can be said to reside inside of the repository, I would argue that "into" is the correct usage here. Compare with the example at your linked site (the URL needs to be fixed, btw) with either turning something "in to " a person (but it's not going into the person), or putting something "into" something else.

Comment: I agree with this. Compare "Turn your homework in to the teacher" with "Check your code into SVN."

Answer (score 1):

I would treat "check in" as a compound term, and so, check some code in to a repository, rather than checking code into a repository.