# "Logged-in", "log-ined", "login-ed", "logined", "log-in-ed", "logged in"?

Tags: phrases, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“log in to” or “log into” or “login to”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/log-in-to-or-log-into-or-login-to)

This following  question, where and how to append "-ed", is not addressed in thу "possible duplicate" in any way.

Which of the following expressions (are they expression, phrase or word?) are correct in technical English?

- logged-in
- log-ined
- login-ed
- log-in-ed
- logined
- logged in
- log ined
- Other? Which?

in relation to a user reading this question?

<strike>Which of the following is correct to use as verb?</strike>

- to login
- to log in
- to log-in

Comment: the answers in the post that I linked above say that the verb is *to log in*. The past tense is therefore *logged in*

Answer (score 47):

*Log in* is a verb, while *login* is a noun. Its Past Tense is *logged in* (*I logged in yesterday*). As an attributive phrase, it is *logged-in* (*logged-in users*).

Comment: I suppose the follow-up question is: why *logged-in* opposed to *logged in*, if *log in* is the verb?

Comment: @Paul: As the past tense of the verb, it would be *logged in*, as in *I logged in this morning.* As an adjectival phrase, it could be either *logged in* or *logged-in*, typically depending on placement, e.g. *Here is a list of users who are logged in* vs. *Here is a list of logged-in users.*