# User login or user-login?

Tags: hyphenation

I don't have enough reputation to make comments on this site (what a weird system), so I have to make this a question on its own.

I am referencing an answer made to another question about the differences between logged-in and logged in, that is located here: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/11002/127722

The user whose answer was accepted, has written his own example which reads:

> the user login was not successful

But isn't that wrong? I thought correct forms would be either:

> the user-login was not successful

Or:

> user's login was not successful

Which is (are) correct?

Comment: As mentioned on the question you linked, *login* is a noun, therefore, *the user login was not successful* is the correct option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*User login* is a perfectly normal kind of noun phrase using a noun as a modifier, exactly like *user experience* or *coffee table*. You could argue that it is redundant (what other kind of login is there?) but it's perfectly grammatical and idiomatic.

*User's login* is also grammatical, and has a slightly different meaning, in that it is relating the login to a (particular) user, rather than qualifying the type of login.

I'm not interested in minutiae of punctuation, but I can't see any reason why you should hyphenate the phrase.