# "Sign in", "signin" or "sign-in"

Tags: word-choice, orthography

Which is correct: *sign in*, *signin* or *sign-in* when used as a noun and also as a verb?

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/log-in-to-or-log-into-or-login-to

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The verb is *sign in*.

The noun is *sign-in*.

The noun is better with the hyphen, because *signin* could be confused with an abbreviated *signing* that's lost its apostrophe.

Alternatively you could use the more common *log in* for the verb, and *login* for the noun.

Comment: I find it interesting that "to log in" is commonly used with computers, but almost never with log books.

Comment: The other bit I recently learned is that the _in_ in _sign in_ should not combine with the preposition _to_.  So you would _sign in to the website_, not _sign into the website_.

Answer (score 6):

The correct version of the verb is *sign in*. Alternatively, you can use *log in*.