# What is the difference between log in, sign in; register, sign up; log out, sign out

Tags: differences, terminology, expression-choice

Although they are all over the Internet, but the answers are not fixed and were not asked all 4s at a time causing me to be confused.

Is it accurate if I say:

- **both login and sign in are the same as authenticate**

  verb, to validate the user. Otherwise password are not required.
- **both logout and sign out are the same**
- **log in is to authenticate into a website that has different interface as guest**

  You cannot use the logged in interface if you are a guest, e.g. Facebook
- **sign in is to authenticate into a website that has same interface as guest**

  You can still use the website without signing in, e.g. Google
- **register is entering your information into the system for your account for serious thing**

  You need to enter your information like name, address, contact number, etc for domain registration. Another example is company registration.
- **sign up is to create an account to use**

  You only need to enter essential information like email, username, password, etc for a Facebook account.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying about "*log **out***" and "*sign ***out***", but these are the antonyms of "*log in*" and "*sign in*". In other words, they're not used for authorization, they're used for "*de-authoization*" (so that another person using the same browser on the same computer can *not* access that user's account). "*Sign up*" and "*register*" are mostly synonymous (as "*sign in*" and "*log in*" are).

Comment: @DanBron , yes, the two words are de-authorization. Both log out and sign out are same, but I never said they are the same to both log in and sign in.Sorry for the confusion because I talking about authorizing word suddenly included de-authorizing words.

Comment: XPmai, in one of your previous edits, "logout" and "signout" were sub-bullets under "sign in"/"login" and included in a sentence about authorization.

Comment: DanBron, no. They were never sub-bullets, you did not see carefully. They were a separate bullet but was at the middle of the first bullet's (login/sign in) description, causing the description of the 1st bullet become description of 2nd bullet (logout/sign out). And the 2nd bullet (logout/ sign out) were not bold, so it looked like identical description. But I have edited it after I realised I added wrong place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [*Difference between "log in", "authenticate" and "sign in"?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/difference-between-log-in-authenticate-and-sign-in). Also [*“Sign in”, “signin” or “sign-in”*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49850/), and [*“log in to” or “log into” or “login to”*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/), and [*Which is standard: “log on/off” or “log in/out”?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33845/), among others.

Comment: No, not duplicate. That only answer half of this question.

Comment: not a duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

There are several different groups of words here.

> log in, sign in, login, log on, logon, authenticate

All of these words are more-or-less synonyms.  "Login"/"logon" may or may not be acceptable (check your style guide).  If they are, they may be nouns instead of verbs (referring to the action of logging in or the state of being logged in).

There is no widely-understood difference between any of these words except as described above.

"Authorize" is not on this list.  In computer security, authorization and authentication are not the same thing.  The items on this list are all authentication.  Authorization refers to deciding what someone is permitted to do after you've established their identity (e.g. on Stack Exchange, moderators are *authorized* to do various things which the rest of us are not).

> log out, sign out, logout, log off, logoff

Likewise, these words are synonyms.  As above, "logout"/"logoff" may not be OK.  Also as above, there is not much meaningful difference between them.  Some of the words in this list do correspond to some of the words in the previous list, so you should probably choose your words to match each other.

> register, sign up

These are synonyms, but they both refer more broadly to providing information in order to receive some service or to be placed on some list.  For instance, you might *sign up* or *register* for a loyalty program at your grocery store.  You could even *sign up* to join the military.

Comment: I understand. But I want more specific difference.

log in and sign in, what difference?

register and sign up, what difference?

logout and sign out, is there really 0 difference?

Comment: As a native speaker, I have never heard of any substantial difference.  There may be subtle usage differences (cf. "large" and "big"), but none come to mind.

Comment: Some words has similar meanings can be interchangeably used but some words cannot. sad and disappointed as similar meaning but cannot be interchangeably used.

Comment: in this case there's essentially no connotative difference. they're so similar that you can find reasonable arguments about which one is the "right" one to use for each of them: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/using-sign-in-vs-using-log-in