# Are "prop the door open" and "prop open the door" both correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

So I feel like "prop open the door" is correct over "prop the door open" because the former splits the verbs, but the latter sounds better to me, for reasons I don't know. Is either correct over the other?

Comment: Both positions for 'open' are acceptable here. Certainly, it is an adjective in 'Prop / hold / keep the door open'; I'm not going into what part of speech it is in 'Prop / keep / hold open the door'. The former variants are more colloquial, the latter sound more poetic. I'm surprised that 'keep ajar the door' has a lot of hits on Google; these things tend to be idiosyncratic. Contrast "keep the bottle open" (232 000) : "keep open the bottle" (a dubious 3).

Comment: _Prop open_ is a pretty ordinary [Phrasal Verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/61686/15299). Note that _prop the door open, prop it open,_ and _prop open the door_ are all fine, but _prop open it_ is ungrammatical. That's [the normal test for phrasal verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/154793/15299). In addition, [this puzzle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/370/Englishphrasalverbs.pdf) may be interesting or helpful. P.S. They all mean the same thing, if they're grammatical; the rule is called Particle Shift.

Comment: I think the word "open" is not needed at all. "Prop the door" and "Do not prop the door" convey the message. Who props a door closed?

Comment: Is prop short for something or is it an actual word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prop the door open

sounds correct, and **open** here is an adverb, not a verb. I would say it is the same structure as

> Hold the door open

or

> Keep the door open

We (well, at least I) don't say `Hold open the door` or `Keep open the door`.

Comment: In 'Prop the door open', 'open' is modifying the noun 'door': it is an object-orientated predicative adjective.

Comment: good to know, after thinking a little it sounds more logical, thanks for correcting