# "Sign into your account" or "Sign in to your account"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, american-english, phrasal-verbs, into-in

Which is correct? Is it that you are signing "into" your account or "in to" your account?

Comment: Similar topic http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/log-in-to-or-log-into-or-login-to?s=1|2.1985

Comment: I read this at first as *turn into your account*. And I have, in the sense that despite all efforts, we're both around 180 pounds.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

At the technology magazines where I've worked, our house style was to say "sign in to" and "log in to" instead of "sign into" and "log into." The rationale was that "sign in" and "log in" are verb phrases, not verb + start-of-a-prepositional-phrase combinations. In practice, however, it is sometimes quite difficult to tell which camp a particular pairing falls into.

For example, it seems reasonable to use the combination "plugged into" in the sentence "Make sure that your charger is plugged into the wall." But what about the figurative use "Zoltan is plugged in to all the latest high-tech developments"? There I'd argue for "plugged in to," on the rationale that "plugged in" (rather than simply "plugged") is essential to the action.

I don't see a bright line here that you can use for guidance in future instances; instead, I see these sorts of phrases as falling on a continuum where deciding between "in to" and "into" is sometimes fairly easy and sometimes quite difficult (and highly subjective). For some people, "sign in to" versus "sign into" may be a difficult call, but in that particular case I think that our house style decision makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously the answer to this is in a state of flux as the technology age continues its maturation.

The rule I've followed for the past few years based on various tech style manuals is that *login* is a noun, while *log* (in the sense of logging in) is a verb. Thus:

What is your login?
I have forgotten my login.
How do I log in to the computer?
How do I log in quickly?

Comment: *Log in* is the verb in the sentence, not *log*, and that is why the correct answer is *in to*.

Answer (score 2):

People are regularly invited to simply *sign in*. As such *sign into* would seems inapposite.

This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sign%20in%2C%20sign%20into&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csign%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csign%20into%3B%2Cc0) strongly supports that view.

Comment: To be fair, that ngram should really be _sign in to_ vs. _sign into_, which yields the opposite results.

Comment: @JoshBurgess I respectfully disagree. The phrase *sign in* is routinely used without being followed by *to*. I think that meme is the overarching one. The fact that it sometimes also takes *to* does not transform the less common *sign into* into the common expression.

Comment: But it does include several false positives in your sample.  The data that should be taken from the ngram isn't the prevalence of one choice over another, but rather the complete lack of prevalence of _sign in to_.  In my opinion, that should be the drive of the relevance of the ngram, not the comparison.  The question is flawed in that _sign in to_ is simply a poor assemblage of words, and should probably be avoided.

Comment: @JoshBurgess - when accessing my sites I "sign in" or "log in" (or, "log on"), but when speaking or writing about "signing/logging in" I must make reference to my destination (what or where). "signing/logging in" strikes me as effective. What drives your assertion that "sign in to" is a poor assemblage of words?

Comment: I think this is the more relevant ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sign+into%2Csign+in+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csign%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csign%20in%20to%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's the standard, but I have read "sign-in to your account", "was signing-in to his account" etc