# "Log in" or "Log on"?

Tags: prepositions

What is correct?

- He was logging **on** to the Bitrack database.
- He was logging **in** to the Bitrack database.
- Please note a password is required to log **on/in** to the database.

Comment: Typically one *logs on* to systems. You *authenticate* with databases.

Comment: related: [“log in to” or “log into” or “login to”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/log-in-to-or-log-into-or-login-to?rq=1)

Comment: One or the other.  Has been thus since 1970, at least.

Comment: (A better question would be why do we use "log" at all.)

Answer (score 0):

You generally log in (when entering usernames and passwords.) Log on can be used just to mean to visit a website, but that's not so common. I don't think you ever log on when you're entering a password unless you're confusing the two terms (which I'm sure happens a lot.)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Manual of Style page 329 states

> *Use log on* or *log on to* to refer to creating a user session on a computer or network.  Use *log off* or *log off from* to refer to ending a user session on a computer or a network  Use *sign in* and *sign out* to refer to creating and ending a user session on the Internet.
>
> Do not use *log in, login, log onto, log off, logout, sign off,* or *sign on* unless these terms appear in the user interface.

All that said, 'on' implies a platform, such as a particular machine or service while 'in' implies being surrounded, such as by data.

Comment: That's just Microsoft's opinion.