# Check source "into" or "in to" SVN?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Checked into the database” versus “checked in to the database”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5219/checked-into-the-database-versus-checked-in-to-the-database)

I understand the difference between "into" and "in to".  The first involves the movement towards the inside of a place.  The latter, is a combination of an adverb and preposition.  This is explained [here](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/into-vs-in-to/).

But, does "into" require that the place be a physical location? If so, I would guess using "in to" would be correct since SVN (or Git, or...) is not a physical location.

Is it more correct to check code into svn or check code in to svn?