# Is it 'buy-in to', 'buy into', or 'buy in to' in the following sentence

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrase-requests

"I don't understand why people `<insert words here>` products that have a reputation of hardware failures."

What is the correct way to form this sentence?

Comment: Doesn't *buy* alone work fine here?

Comment: *Buy* alone wouldn't work because it doesn't demonstrate a continued interest or investment in the products.

Comment: *Into* is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct form:

> "I don't understand why people **buy into** products that have a reputation of hardware failures."

See 15th definition of *buy* on [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/buy):

> **15.**
>   buy into, to purchase a share, interest, or membership in: *They tried to buy into the club but were not accepted.*

There is also a slightly more metaphorical, but not uncommon, sense of this phrase, listed in [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/buy+into):

> **2.** *Informal* To believe in, especially wholeheartedly or uncritically: *couldn't buy into that brand of conservatism.*

Comment: There's [another definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/buy+into) of *buy into* which isn't in Dictionary.com: *2. Informal To believe in, especially wholeheartedly or uncritically: **couldn't buy into that brand of conservatism.*** It's not clear which of these definitions, if either, the OP intended.

Comment: Using the verb *to buy into* as believing in something is far from being informal.

Answer (score 3):

[Buy-in](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/buy-in) is a noun, meaning:

> the fact of accepting a policy or change because you agree with it
> *If you want to make major changes you need buy-in from everyone in the organization.*

To [buy into something](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/buy_1#buy_1__27), a verb, means:

> to believe something, especially an idea that many other people believe in
> *She had never bought into the idea that to be attractive you have to be thin.*

It would be possible to write your sentence with "buy in to", but this is not common:

**[buy-in to](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=11232611)**    **9** *(these uses are still as a noun, just located before "to")*
**[buy in to](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=11232608)**   **18**
**[buy into](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=11232614)**   **845** occurrences in COCA

Note that this search includes transcripts of spoken English as well as various written sources; you shouldn't put too much stock in the exact numbers, but the trend is clear. Readers will understand if you write:

> I don't understand why people **buy into** products that have a reputation of hardware failures.

Comment: In this case, *in to* is strictly incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

I would say that it should be "buy in to".

A very similar question was asked in ["Log into/login to/log in to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/log-in-to-or-log-into-or-login-to), which I believe applies nicely here as well.  And in that answer, another question/answer was referenced ( ["into vs. in to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5219/into-versus-in-to/5221#5221)) which also seems very relevant.

Comment: The verb is *to buy into*, not *to buy in*, so it should be put as one word.