# "Into" vs "in to"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should “into” be used rather than “in to,” and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/when-should-into-be-used-rather-than-in-to-and-vice-versa)

[Google Support](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=48090#K):

> 1. Visit Google.com.
> 2. Search for NS lookup.
> 3. Select a search result from the list.
> 4. Type your web publishing address **in to** the field.
> 5. Select CNAME record if it's not the default search query.
> 6. Click Submit, or Lookup.

Shouldn't it have been *into* instead of *in to*? Or am I misunderstanding something with regard to the language used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Into is "used as a function word to indicate entry, introduction, insertion, superposition, or inclusion." I believe it would be better to use *into* rather than *in to* here, especially since *typing in* is somewhat redundant.

Also, instead of *typing* the address, it would be better to "Enter your web publishing address into the field."

Comment: you are saying you are smarter than Google!

Comment: No, Google is part of my brain and I make mistakes.  :)

Comment: i'm not understanding you

Comment: Just a bad joke -- some say Google is an extension of our memories.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s Pam Peters (‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’) on the matter:

> The spaced form ensures that the particle 'in' is interpreted in
>   relation to the previous verb, and adds a detail of movement that
>   would otherwise be submerged. But in practice the solid form “into”
>   might be justified, and not too much is lost.

Like the previous poster, I would myself use the solid form in the example given, on the grounds that the 'in' is **not** to be interpreted in relation to the previous verb.