# "Translate into" vs. "Translate to"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Does one translate a word or phrase *into* another language or *to* another language? For example:

- Translate the following phrase to Spanish.
- Translate the following phrase into Spanish.

Comment: related: [When should “into” be used rather than “in to,” and vice versa?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/when-should-into-be-used-rather-than-in-to-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Does one need to evaluate what's important in life or does one give up?

Answer (score 33):

In my experience/dialect, you use *translate into* when you are talking about the target **language**, but you can optionally use *translate to* when you are talking about the target **text** (the specific equivalent for the piece of original text you're talking about).

For example, all of these are acceptable:

> (1) I translated "I like cats" into Spanish.
>
> (2) I translated "I like cats" into "Me gustan los gatos."
>
> (3) I translated "I like cats" to "Me gustan los gatos."

Note that *translate to* is very commonly used intransitively, e.g.:

> (4) "I like cats" translates to "Me gustan los gatos."

However, you can't use *translate into* intransitively, and you can't *translate to* a language as a whole. Thus, these are unacceptable:

> (1a) *I translated "I like cats" to Spanish.
>
> (4a) *"I like cats" translates into "Me gustan los gatos."

Answer (score 12):

As far as translation is concerned, you translate **into** another language. You don't translate **to** it.

Comment: Do you have a cite?

Comment: @jwpat7: Apart from my own experience and practice, the OED has five citations for ‘translate to’ and none of them concerns language. It has 42 for ‘translate into’ and almost all concern language. There may be rare instances where ‘translate to [language]’ are found, but if the OP is asking for straightforward advice, I believe I have given it.

Comment: @jwpat7: It's the general case. See [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=translate+to%2Ctranslate+into&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for evidence that *translate to* is rarely used in *any* context.

Comment: The only context in which I've heard *translate to* is when the subject of the verb is also the thing that's being translated (e.g., *X, which translates to Y, is...*).

Comment: Is there any semantic difference between these two cases?

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Apparently no semantic differences have been mentioned, and the arguments advanced so far against *translate to* equate to "We don't do that".  Which is true, albeit not educational.

Comment: @jwpat7: Lots of language is "we don't do that". But I was thinking about this a bit more and I think that there might be a general rule for transformations: "He was turned into a toad", "The robot transformed into a truck", "It was translated into Spanish", etc.

Comment: @jwpat7: If the OP wants a treatise on the history and many and varied uses of 'translate' with and without different prepositions, then I'm sure, given time, energy and space, several of us could provide it. If, as I suspect, he wants a pragmatic answer to a straightforward question, then that answer is that 'translate into [language]' is a better bet than 'translate to [language]'.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New 安宇: Yes, 'into' tends, I would say, to be used where motion, actual or figurative, is of the essence of the preceding verb, particularly with the sense of passing through .

Answer (score 12):

According to the *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*, the *BBC English dictionary* and the *OED* one translates **into** another language.

*Translate to* is used alongside *translate into* in a sentence like :

> The rates translate to monthly payments of $399...

and *translate to* is used when translating something to something :

> This book was translated to film....

But google gives hundreds of instances of use of "translate **to**" another language.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/translate

use dictionary :)

1 CHANGE LANGUAGES [intransitive, transitive] to change written or spoken words into another language → interpret

translate something (from something) into something
 Translate the text from Italian into English.
 Poetry doesn’t usually translate well.

translate as
 Dagda, an ancient Irish deity, literally translates as ‘the good god’.