# "String of numbers" vs. "field of numbers"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

I'm trying to choose a name for a variable in my program that includes some number tandem.
What is the difference between *string* and *field* in this case? For example, which one is better: "field of numbers" or "string of numbers"?

Comment: What is the context? What are you trying to say? Neither of these is a common expression in ordinary English, and in mathematics and physics they are very different concepts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about variable naming.

Comment: @Jim: Approximately you are right. But I needed my answer to have a good choose for my work.

Comment: _string_ is a 1-dimensional metaphor. _field_ is a two-dimensional metaphor. Mathematically, _field_ can be expanded to more than two dimensions, so it's a container metaphor, whereas _string_ is linear no matter how you approach it.

Comment: @PeterShor Approximately you are right. I can change it to format of problems like [http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/when-should-into-be-used-rather-than-in-to-and-vice-versa]. Is it a right work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is likely to depend on context. From a scientific or computing viewpoint (given that you have asked about numbers), there is a difference.

Field is likely to define an area or container in which particular items may be found. A database or spreadsheet may contain a field which may only contain types of data (such as numbers, text, dates etc.) Graphical data may define one of its axes as a field.

String would represent a collection of similar or related items. In computing, a string represents a linear sequence of characters, numbers or other data.

So, you can have both a field of numbers and a string of numbers. What's more, a field of numbers is likely to contain a string of numbers! 
However, if you are asking about general phrase usage, I'd be likely to suggest a string of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

string is a rope, field is a carpet

field contains string, but string doesn't contain field.
like knitting, or typing a text, as soon as you use the return key, you start building up a field made out of a string. the field is a 2-dimensional organisation of a string. type a string of letters, or numbers, into a field.