# Drag and drop video into OR drag and drop video in to

Tags: prepositions

Which is more correct?

I’ve created a web page that you can just drag and drop the videos **in to**:

http://...

OR

I’ve created a web page that you can just drag and drop the videos **into**:

http://...

Comment: "Broadly speaking, in refers to something that already exists inside something, while into implies motion from outside to inside." from http://english.stackexchange.com/a/18149/59389 - Therefore, it would appear to be better to use "into" as we want to, for example, to drag the videos from the desktop into the web page - hmmm, or maybe that should be "on to" - doh!

Comment: "into which you can drop the video"?

Comment: I settled on 'into' in the end. @TimLymington thanks, yes that will avoid a trailing preposition as well. - in full, "I’ve created a web page into which you can drop the videos."

Answer (score 0):

*In to* only works when *to* is introducing an infinitive.  I don't seen anything wrong with the simpler form:  I've created a web page that you can just drop the videos in.

Comment: I've updated original as I should have said that the drop here is really part of the computer phase to 'drag and drop' something.