# Meaning of 'Must not' and how to make the another meaning

Tags: meaning, antonyms

I want to ask a question.

The opposite of "must" is "must not", everybody knows.
But, what does "must not" mean?
Does it mean that you "may choose to do or not do" or you "may not choose to do"?
Or it depends on the situation?

Comment: Hello, Jamie. This is the sort of question to ask on the sister site, ELL.

Comment: _Must not `VP`_ means 'It is necessary/obligatory that not `VP`', i.e, don't do `VP`. That's because the modal is outside the negative scope. Since _must_ is a modal, it has a paraphrase: _have to `VP`_ (**always** pronounced with an /f/, never a /v/), which means the same as _must_ in the affirmative, but has the opposite meaning in the negative. _Not have to `VP`_ means 'It is not necessary/obligatory that `VP`, i.e, there's no obligation to do `VP`, because here the negative is outside the modal.

Comment: Since I can't post a comment on [the later question you just deleted](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150908/), I'll just say here that it would probably have gotten closed as a duplicate of [When should “into” be used rather than “in to,” and vice versa?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/). In your case, I think your test is ***wrong***. You do in fact *walk **into** a job interview* (one word). If you can cite the source of the test, I think you should ask it again, because many people get this usage wrong  (just don't admit that you're doing it for *homework!* :)

Comment: Thank you, @FumbleFingers. You really helped me a lot, i admit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As *must* expresses obligation, so *must not* expresses prohibition.

Comment: I can't wait to start quoting.

Comment: And the 'lack of obligation' is usually expressed *need not*.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your question, *you must not* means *you do not have the permission or rights to do whatever*. This is equivalent to your second alternative: "*you may not choose to do*".

Hence, *you must not* does **not** mean your first alternative "*you may choose to do or not do*".

This is confusing to German learners of English in particular because the German verb *müssen* behaves differently from the English *must*, whereby "*du musst nicht*" does indeed mean "*you may choose to do or not do*".

For example:

> Du musst nicht gehen

does not mean "*You must not go*".

It means "*you don't have to go; you may choose to go or not to go.*"

---

Note: This answer is a simplistic account of just one of the functions of the complex English modal *must*.

Comment: Thinking through your answer, it also confuses erstwhile learners of Germans in reverse or at least it had confused this one.

Comment: @virmaior, Yes, I remember getting confused early on in Germany when I was invited to an optional meeting with the words: _Du musst nicht kommen_.

Answer (score -1):

If you must do something, it means there is a breath of urgency in that statement. If something must be done, then there usually follows an immediate consequence. The same follows for things that must not be done. Consequence for things that must not be done follows when something is not omitted from the action. Therefore if someone must not speak in public and instead speaks in public, a consequence may follow (which is often immediate in nature); however, it might not. Which makes this statement a rather dramatic one -- while also urgent; however, in most cases when something must or must not be done, a consequence does follow due to reason the person used "must" rather than "should." Should holds a potential consequence as well, yet that consequence may not be as immediate. Should is often used in philosophy when must is often used in upholding a law that has a severe punishment.

Comment: At a minimum, this answer might benefit from the use of paragraphs. But I'm not sure why *must* would be said to have *a breath of urgency*. Moreover, there's no clear relation between must/must not and consequences. What is clear is prohibition or obligation...

Comment: @virmaior: All I can say is you must not have been thinking of usages like my sentence here, when you wrote that. What *is* clear is the concept of *necessity/certainty*, which might or might not imply prohibition or obligation.

Comment: You must be right, but must you type that way?

Answer (score -1):

"Must not" means it is urgent, that something is prohibited to be done. It should prevent you from doing anything. If prohibition is not urgent, then you can use "need not."