# Differences in meanings between 'in to' and 'into'

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between 'into' and 'in to'?

Is there a difference in meaning or with usage?

I was unable to find anything on other websites.

Comment: The answer provided below should suffice. Also, I've provided a link below the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Into is a preposition.

In and to are words that can take on many different meanings.

[This article](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/08/in-to-versus-into/) from ODO gives the following handy rules for when you should use into vs in to, and also explores the question in some depth.

> Is to part of an infinitive verb or is it a preposition?

If yes, always write in and to as separate words:

> ✔ Ministers stepped in to resolve the crisis. (in is part of the
>   phrasal verb step in; to resolve is an infinitive verb form)
>
> ✔ I just dropped in to see how you were. (in is part of the phrasal
>   verb drop in; to see is an infinitive verb form)
>
> ✔ He listened in to our phone call. (in is part of the phrasal verb
>   listen in; to is a preposition that belongs with the noun phrase our
>   phone call)

Does into appear in conjunction with a verb (or phrasal verb) of
movement, action, or change, and is it functioning as a preposition
that’s linked in meaning to a noun or pronoun?

If yes, always write into as one word:

> ✔ When I first stepped into the room, I had no idea of its size. (step
>   is a simple verb of movement; into is a preposition)
>
> ✔ Oh no! I dropped my phone into the bath! (drop is a simple verb of
>   action; into is a preposition)
>
> ✔ Their company ran into financial difficulties. (run into is a
>   phrasal verb)
>
> ✔ He didn’t go into detail about the accident. (go into is a phrasal
>   verb)

Comment: Well put. There's also an answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/when-should-into-be-used-rather-than-in-to-and-vice-versa

Comment: It is fortunate that you did. Your take on this question will help,primarily because this is basically what every English user should know.