# When to use "In" or "Into"

Tags: prepositions

When will I use "In" and when will I use "Into" in making sentences?
Does it have a difference? or in can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should "into" be used rather than "in to," and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/when-should-into-be-used-rather-than-in-to-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 2):

While they are both prepositions, they are **not** the same thing. See dictionary definitions [in](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in?s=t) and [into](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/into?s=t).

- **In** -  used to indicate inclusion within space, a place, or limits
- **Into** - toward or in the direction of

Here's some examples to highlight the differences:

`He is in the bar` vs `He walks into the bar` 
`I'm in big trouble` vs `I'm heading into trouble`

Comment: You're welcome. If you're satisfied by this answer, please mark it as such. Thanks!