# “Pull in to” or “pull into”? “Head in to”, “Head into”, “head to”, or “head for”?

Tags: phrases, prepositions, sentence, formality

My question may sound weird, but what which of these is correct?

“She pulled in to the parking lot”
“She pulled into the parking lot”

“I was heading for school.”
“I was heading to school.”

“I was heading in to the school”
“I was heading into the school.”

Thanks lots!

Comment: Hi Nina, this question really belongs on the English Language Learners' site.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U;  Please, only one question.at a time.

Comment: Hi Lambie! I didn’t know there was a site for English learners. I came across that site a few days ago, so I am somehow “new” in this whole thing. Thanks for the advice, though!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should "into" be used rather than "in to," and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/when-should-into-be-used-rather-than-in-to-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

"To pull in" is an intransitive phrasal verb. You can just say "Pull in!"

"To pull into" is transitive, you cannot just say "Pull into!", you must pull into *something*, e.g. "Pull into that car park!"

Comment: So if I say “he pulled into the parking lot” it’s correct? 
And if I say “pull in!” (As an order), it’s correct, too?

Comment: @Nina - Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help!

Comment: 'Pull into' is also a MWV.

Comment: There is also a transitive phrasal verb *to pull in*, as in *Pull in your gut soldier!* or "Pull in your (fishing) line!"

Answer (score -1):

**To pull in** indicates a change of direction: “She pulled into the parking lot” -> “She turned off a particular road and into the parking lot”.

OED

> **7.b. Of a driver or vehicle: to drive off or to the side of the road, esp. in order to stop.**
>
> 2001   T. Hanley in M. Hickey Irish Days (2004) 125   *This side of Tulla there was a bit of a blind laneway and I'd pull in there and have a flask of tea.*

**To head** = to move in a particular (usually forward) direction

OED:

> **20. Originally Nautical. With adverb or prepositional phrase.**
>
> **a.** intransitive. **To move forwards in a specified direction or towards a particular place or thing. Later also more generally: to go, make one's way. Also transitive: to follow (a course, way, etc.) in a specified direction.**
>
> 2008   A. Nersesian Sacrificial Circumcision of Bronx 261   *Once he had located the address of the Russian embassy in the phone book, he headed over in a cab*

Comment: OP is asking for help deciding between 'She pulled in to the parking lot' and 'She pulled into the parking lot'. 'Pull in' is the intransitive MWV; 'pull into' the transitive analogue.